Problems deleting single item from Firebase Realtime Database. React Native
I try to build a mobile app, where you can create a team and players. And save it in to database. I am able to do that, but I have problem when I try to create deleting function for single player. I can delete whole team, that's working, but I can't delete single player. Bottom of this question is my database.
Here is how I created team in to database:
const createTeam = async () => {
     const userTeamRef = ref(database, 'users/' + userId + '/teams');
     const newTeamRef = push(userTeamRef);
     const newTeamKey = newTeamRef.key;
 
     
     const teamID = newTeamKey;
 
     const teamRef = ref(database, 'teams/' + teamID);
     const newTeam = {
         teamID: teamID, 
         name: teamName,
         players: players.map(player => ({
             playerID: player.playerID,
             name: player.name,
             stats: playerStats[player.playerID] || {
                 plus: false,
                 minus: false,
                 shot: false,
                 shotOnGoal: false
             }
         })),
     };
     try {
         await set(teamRef, newTeam);
         console.log('New team created successfully!');
     } catch (error) {
         console.error('Error creating new team:', error);
     }
 };
 

 const addPlayer = () => {
     const playerID = push(ref(database, 'players')).key; 
     setPlayers([...players, { name: playerName, playerID }]); 
     setPlayerStats(prevState => ({
         ...prevState,
         [playerID]: { 
             name: playerName,
             plus: false,
             minus: false,
             shot: false,
             shotOnGoal: false
         }
     }));
     setPlayerName('');
 };

And here is deleting methods from other component:
useEffect(() => {
 const teamsRef = ref(database, 'teams');
 onValue(teamsRef, (snapshot) => {
   const data = snapshot.val();
   if (data) {
     const teamsArray = Object.values(data);
     setTeams(teamsArray);
   }
 });

 return () => {
   
 };
 }, []);

 useEffect(() => {
 if (selectedTeam) {
   setPlayers(selectedTeam.players); 
 } else {
   setPlayers([]); 
 }
 }, [selectedTeam]);

 const handleDeletePlayer = (playerID) => {
 console.log("Deleting player", playerID);

 if (selectedTeam) {
   const teamRef = ref(database, `teams/${selectedTeam.teamID}/players/${playerID}`);
   console.log(teamRef);
   remove(teamRef)
     .then(() => {
       console.log(playerID, 'successful removed');
       
       setPlayers(prevPlayers => prevPlayers.filter(player => player.playerID != playerID));
       console.log(players);
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       console.error('Error removing player:', error);
     });
 }
};

 const handleDeleteTeam = () => {
  if (selectedTeam) {
    const teamRef = ref(database, `teams/${selectedTeam.teamID}`);
   remove(teamRef)
     .then(() => {
       console.log(selectedTeam.teamID, 'successful removed');
       setPlayers([]);
       setSelectedTeam(null);
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       console.error('Error removing team:', error);
     });
  }
 };

And if I wrote this correct, here is database:
{
  "-NvajG9MkZFjZXgrAn-E": {
   "name": "Canada",
  "players": [
  {
    "0": {
      "name": "Sidney Crosby",
      "playerID": "-NvajBsvVwe7bJ6kbXXh",
      "stats": {}
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "name": "Connor McDavid",
      "playerID": "-NvajFnxRRfc74Vg7Ysu",
      "stats": {}
    }
  }
],
"teamID": "-NvajG9MkZFjZXgrAn-E"
}
}


Your code to delete a player from a team doesn't match with your data structure. The code:
ref(database, `teams/${selectedTeam.teamID}/players/${playerID}`);

The data structure:
{
  "-NvajG9MkZFjZXgrAn-E": {
   "name": "Canada",
  "players": [
  {
    "0": {
      "name": "Sidney Crosby",
      "playerID": "-NvajBsvVwe7bJ6kbXXh",
      "stats": {}
    }
  },

This would work if playerID is "0", but my guess is that it actually is "-NvajBsvVwe7bJ6kbXXh".
You only option in the current data structure is to:

Load the entire team
Remove the player from the players array in JavaScript code (for example with a filter)
Write the entire array back to the database


While the above approach will work, it is not ideal. The better approach is to change your data structure to better match the use-case:
"players": {
  "-NvajBsvVwe7bJ6kbXXh": {
    "name": "Sidney Crosby",
    "stats": {}
  }
  "-NvajFnxRRfc74Vg7Ysu": {
    "name": "Connor McDavid",
    "stats": {}
  }
}

So now players is no longer an array, but it's a set of key values - where each key is the ID of a player. This has the advantage that each player can (by definition) only occur once in a team.
With the new data structure, your current code to delete a player actually works.
